# Number of bytes read from recv function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pipe

I would like to specify how many bytes to read from The pipe. For instance, in one process I'm writing two strings and i would like to read them all together, but it reads only one.

Is that possible?

```
import multiprocessing
def mds(handle):
    handle.send(['teste'])
    handle.send(['teste2'])
def plot(handle):
    b = handle.recv() 
    print(b)

def Comunicacao():
    hRead, hWrite = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=mds, args=(hWrite,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=plot, args=(hRead,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
if __name__=='__main__':
    k=0
    while k<20:
        Comunicacao()
        k+=1
```

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection) shows that it doesn't send it as string but it uses `pickle` to convert it special object with extra information which helps to recognize if it received all data - so you can't set how many bytes to read. You would have to send both strings in one send `['teste', 'teste2']` or you would have to use `recv()` two times. There is also `send_bytes` and `recv_bytes` and maybe it could receive it as one string - but you don't know how many bytes it will  send.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.